# CKEditor insert link dialog with display text field

Tags: ckeditor

Default add link functionality requires user to first pre-select the text in editor and then click the Link button and enter the url in dialog.

Is it possible to setup the plugin to enable the 'Display text' field inside the dialog? 
(same as gmail add link feature)

This way user can start inserting link by clicking on Link button in toolbar and define both text and url, rather then pre-selecting the text.

Comment: This has been requested a number of times, but so far it's not possible to do it without modifying the source code.

Comment: Interesting, I guess this would be a typical example of how something apparently trivial cant be done easily due to framework design.